# Creating lists in the middle of program

Tags: python

so I made this program that would store data of a "supermarket list" of things I ought to buy or whatever , I was wondering how could I give an option to create another list to store other kind of things . That's most of it , and it's done just want to put that option in the program so  I can make a GUI.

```
choice = None

food = []

drink =[]

trash = []

print("Esta é uma aplicação de armazenamento \n")

while choice != 0:

    print("0 - Sair \n"

          "1 - adicionar à lista\n"

          "2 - Remover de lista \n"

          "3 - Mover para lixeira \n"

          "4 - Listar itens \n"

          "5 - Listar itens na lixeira \n")

    choice = input("Insira a opção desejada \n")

    if choice == "0":
        choice = 0
        print("Obrigado por usar nosso software")


    elif choice == "1":
        a =input("1 - Inserir em comidas;2 - Inserir em bebidas\n")

        if a =="1":
            b = input("Insira a comida desejada para sua lista: ")
            food.append(b)

        if a =="2":
            b = input("Insira a bebida desejada para sua lista: ")
            drink.append(b)


    elif choice == "2":
        a = input("1 - Remover de comidas ;2 - Remover de bebidas\n")
        if a == "1":
            b = input("Remova a comida desejada da sua lista: ")
            food.remove(b)

        if a == "2":
            b = input("Remova a bebida desejada para sua lista: ")
            drink.remove(b)

    elif choice == "3":
        a = input("Mover da lista de comidas : 1 ; Bebidas : 2")
        if a == "1":
            b = input("Insira o valor que deseja mover: ")
            trash.append(b)
            food.remove(b)

        if a == "2":
            b = input("Remova a bebida desejada para sua lista: ")
            trash.append(b)
            drink.remove(b)



    elif choice == "4":
        print("Estes são os itens na lista de comida: " )
        for item in food:
            print(item)
        print("Estes são os itens na lista de bebidas: ")
        for item in drink:
            print(item)


    elif choice == "5":
        for item in trash:
            print("Estes são os itens na lista de comida: "+item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a dictionary here:

```
items = {
    'food': [],
    'drink': [],
    'trash': []
}
```

Then your code could add whatever new category the user wants by doing something like so:

```
choice = input("Insira a opção desejada \n")
b = input("Insira a comida desejada para sua lista: ")

try:
    items[choice].append(b)
except KeyError:
    items[choice] = [b]
```

Note that you would have to remake or do away with the number system to handle the arbitrary list name.

Comment: You could also use `defaultdict(list)` so you wouldn't have to do a `try/except`.